# I need to retrieve the department, which has the max(avg(salary)) for each region from table hr (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to retrieve the highest average salary group by regions from table hr (oracle)
Output should be: Region, department_name, max(avg(salary))
Can't output region and department_name together

```
    SELECT
t1.region_name,
MAX(t1.avg)FROM
(
    SELECT
        region_name,
        department_name,
        round(AVG(salary) ) AS avg
    FROM
        regions reg
        INNER JOIN countries coun ON reg.region_id = coun.region_id
        INNER JOIN locations loc ON coun.country_id = loc.country_id
        INNER JOIN departments dep ON loc.location_id = dep.location_id
        INNER JOIN employees emp ON emp.department_id = dep.department_id
    GROUP BY
        region_name,
        department_name
    ORDER BY 3
) t1GROUP BY t1.region_name
```

Comment: please write the error you are getting during execution of query.

Comment: Also department name won't be appear in result because you are not selecting it in your outer select query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I don't have a mistake, but when I add "t1.department_name" in the first row   (like this: SELECT t1.region_name, t1.department_name
MAX(t1.avg)FROM.........) it doesn't work correctly, even if I change group by
So, i don't know how to add coloumn with department
I need something like this:
america    executives    19000
europe      pr                 10000

Comment: The "highest average salary group by regions" is not precise. You expect a region and a department in your results. So I expect you are looking for the department(s) per region that have the highest avarage salary in that region. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, sorry, that I didn't clarify right!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for the department(s) per region that have the highest avarage salary in that region. So you'd rank your joined rows by the avarage salary and keep the highest ranked rows:

```
SELECT
  region_name,
  department_name,
  avg_salary
FROM
(
  SELECT
    reg.region_name,
    dep.department_name,
    AVG(emp.salary) AS avg_salary,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY reg.region_name ORDER BY AVG(emp.salary) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM regions reg
    INNER JOIN countries coun ON reg.region_id = coun.region_id
    INNER JOIN locations loc ON coun.country_id = loc.country_id
    INNER JOIN departments dep ON loc.location_id = dep.location_id
    INNER JOIN employees emp ON emp.department_id = dep.department_id
  GROUP BY reg.region_name, dep.department_name
)
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY region_name, department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
 SELECT
t1.region_name,
t1.department_name,
t1.avg FROM
(
    SELECT
        reg.region_name,
        dep.department_name,
        round(AVG(salary) ) AS avg
    FROM
        regions reg
        INNER JOIN countries coun ON reg.region_id = coun.region_id
        INNER JOIN locations loc ON coun.country_id = loc.country_id
        INNER JOIN departments dep ON loc.location_id = dep.location_id
        INNER JOIN employees emp ON emp.department_id = dep.department_id
    GROUP BY
        reg.region_name,
        dep.department_name
    ORDER BY avg(SALARY) desc limit 1
) t1 Order BY t1.region_name, t1.department_name;
```